# Any way to reverse the direction of comparisons when using emmeans contrast with "interaction" argument?

Tags: r, emmeans

I'm trying to use `emmeans` to test "contrasts of contrasts" with custom orthogonal contrasts applied to a zero-inflated negative binomial model. The study design has 4 groups (study_group: grp1, grp2, grp3, grp4), each of which is assessed at 3 timepoints (time: Time1, Time2, Time3).

With the code below, I am able to get very close to, but not exactly, what I want. The contrasts that emerge are expressed in terms of ratios such as grp1/grp2, grp1/grp3,..., grp3/grp4 ("lower over higher"; see output following code).

What would be immensely helpful to me to have a way to flip these ratios to be grp2/grp1, grp3/grp1,..., grp4/grp3 ("higher over lower"). I've tried sticking `reverse=TRUE` in various spots, but to no effect.

Short of re-leveling the study_group factor, is there anyway to do this in `emmeans`?

Thanks!

```
library(glmmTMB)
library(emmeans)

set.seed(3456)

# Building grid for study design: 4 groups of 3 sites, 
#  each with 20 participants observed 3 times 
site <- rep(1:12, each=60)
pid <- 1000*site+10*(rep(rep(1:20,each=3),12))
study_group <- c(rep("grp1",180), rep("grp2",180), rep("grp3",180), rep("grp4",180))
grp_num <- c(rep(0,180), rep(1,180), rep(2,180), rep(3,180))
time <- c(rep(c("Time1", "Time2", "Time3"),240))
time_num <- c(rep(c(0:2),240))

# Site-level random effects (intercepts)
site_eff_count = rep(rnorm(12, mean = 0, sd = 0.5), each = 60)
site_eff_zeros = rep(rnorm(12, mean = 0, sd = 0.5), each = 60)

# Simulating a neg binomial outcome
y_count <- rnbinom(n = 720, mu=exp(3.25 + grp_num*0.15 + time_num*-0.20 + grp_num*time_num*0.15 + site_eff_count), size=0.8)

# Simulating some extra zeros
log_odds = (-1.75 + grp_num*0.2 + time_num*-0.40 + grp_num*time_num*0.50 + site_eff_zeros)
prob_1 = plogis(log_odds)
prob_0 = 1 - prob_1
y_zeros <- rbinom(n = 720, size = 1, prob = prob_0) 

# Building datasest with ZINB-ish outcome
data_ZINB <- data.frame(site, pid, study_group, time, y_count, y_zeros)
data_ZINB$y_obs <- ifelse(y_zeros==1, y_count, 0)

# Estimating ZINB GLMM in glmmTMB
mod_ZINB <- glmmTMB(y_obs ~ 1 
                    + study_group + time + study_group*time
                    + (1|site),
                    family=nbinom2,
                    zi = ~ .,
                    data=data_ZINB)
#summary(mod_ZINB)

# Getting model-estimated "cell" means for conditional (non-zero) sub-model
#  in response (not linear predictor) scale
count_means <- emmeans(mod_ZINB, 
                       pairwise ~ time | study_group, 
                       component="cond", 
                       type="response", 
                       adjust="none")
# count_means

# Defining custom contrast function for orthogonal time contrasts
#  contr1 = Time 2 - Time 1
#  contr2 = Time 3 - Times 1 and 2
compare_arms.emmc <- function(levels) {
  k <- length(levels)
  contr1 <- c(-1,1,0)
  contr2 <- c(-1,-1,2)
  coef <- data.frame()
  coef <- as.data.frame(lapply(seq_len(k - 1), function(i) {
    if(i==1) contr1 else contr2
  }))
  names(coef) <- c("T1vT2", "T1T2vT3")
  attr(coef, "adjust") = "none"
  coef
}

# Estimating pairwise between-group "contrasts of contrasts"
#  i.e., testing if time contrasts differ across groups
compare_arms_contrast <- contrast(count_means[[1]], 
                                  interaction = c("compare_arms", "pairwise"), 
                                  by = NULL)
compare_arms_contrast
```

applying the`emmeans::contrast` function as above yields this:

```
 time_compare_arms study_group_pairwise ratio    SE  df null t.ratio p.value
 T1vT2             grp1 / grp2          1.091 0.368 693    1   0.259  0.7957
 T1T2vT3           grp1 / grp2          0.623 0.371 693    1  -0.794  0.4276
 T1vT2             grp1 / grp3          1.190 0.399 693    1   0.520  0.6034
 T1T2vT3           grp1 / grp3          0.384 0.241 693    1  -1.523  0.1283
 T1vT2             grp1 / grp4          0.664 0.245 693    1  -1.108  0.2681
.
.
.
 T1T2vT3           grp3 / grp4          0.676 0.556 693    1  -0.475  0.6346

Tests are performed on the log scale
```

Comment: does `MASS::contr.sdif` get you anywhere?  Any chance of a reproducible example? (For figuring out contrasts you can probably substitute a Poisson GLM for the ZINB, since the machinery for contrasts will be the same.)

Comment: @BenBolker It will take me a while to put together a meaningful example. FWIW, the data are being analyzed using a mixed effects ZINB estimated in ```glmmTMB```. 

I'll take a look at the ```MASS``` documentation to see if that function will get me to what I want and also will try to build an example that works. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I looked at the documentation for ```MASS::contr.sdif```, but it wasn't obvious to me that it could give anything that ```emmeans::contrast``` does not.  I now include an example that illustrates the kind of output I have been getting.

Comment: Why wouldn't this just be `1/ratio`?

Comment: Doesn't `"rev pairwise"` get you somewhere? And I'll mention that functions for coding factors in regression really are not close to what is needed by `emmeans::contrast`; not does the coding of predictors have any effect on `emmeans` results.

Comment: Argh! I completely missed the **multiple** mentions of ```revpairwise``` in the ```emmeans``` documentation. Mea culpa, mea culpa. Replacing ```pairwise``` with ```revpairwise```  in the ```contrast``` statement does exactly what I have been looking for. Thanks and apologies for not being a more careful reader.

Comment: Russ, I didn't immediately pick up on what you were saying was about the functions I had written. An interesting (to me) feature: no matter how effects are coded in the mixed model (default dummy coding vs. contrast coding), p-values for the interactions match (to ≥ 3 decimals) across models and the interaction contrasts, BUT the between-arm ratio values derived from the ```emmeans``` step and my contrasts differ noticeably (e.g., T2-T1 in grp2 vs. grp1 = .916 from ```emmeans``` vs. .957 from contrast).  As expected, exponentiated model coefficients exactly match ```emmeans```-derived ratios.

Answer (score 2):

The answer, provided by [Russ Lenth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3961566/russ-lenth) in the comments and in the `emmeans` documentation for the `contrast` function, is to replace `pairwise` with `revpairwise` in the `contrast` function call.